# Increasing speed for comparative analysis using Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have been thinking about this problem for a while now and I was hoping that someone here would have a suggestion to considerably increase the speed of this analysis using Python.

I basically have two files. File (1) contains coordinates composed of a letter, a start and an end: e.g. "a  1000   1100" and file (2) a dataset in which each datapoint in composed of a letter and a coordinate: e.g. "p  1350". What I am trying to do with the script is to count how many datapoints fall within the borders of the coordinates, but only if the letter of the datapoint from file (2) and the coordinate from file (1) are equal. In real life datasets file (1) contains > 50K coordinates and file (2) > 50 million datapoints. Increasing the amount of datapoints exponentially increases the time my script requires to run. So I wonder if someone could come up with a more time-efficient way.

Thanks!

My script starts at  # script strategy, but I first simulate a minimal example dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import string

# simulate data

c_size = 10
d_size = 1000000

# letters
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

# coordinates
c1 = np.random.randint(low=100000, high=2000000, size=c_size)
c2 = np.random.randint(low=100, high=1000, size=c_size)

# data
data = np.random.randint(low=100000, high=2000000, size=d_size)

# script strategy

# create coordinates and count dict
c_dict = {}
count_dict = {}
for start,end in zip(c1,c2):
    end = start + end
    c_l = random.choice(letters)
    ID = c_l + '_' + str(start) + '_' + str(end)
    count_dict[ID] = 0
    if c_l not in c_dict:
        c_dict[c_l] = [[start,end]]
    else:
        c_dict[c_l].append([start,end])

# count how many datapoints (x) are within the borders of the coordinates 
for i in range(d_size):
    d_l = random.choice(letters)
    x = data[i]
    if d_l in c_dict:
        # increasing speed by only comparing data and coordinates with identical letter identifier
        for coordinates in c_dict[d_l]:
            start = coordinates[0]
            end = coordinates[1]
            ID = d_l + '_' + str(start) + '_' + str(end)
            if x >= start and x <= end:
                count_dict[ID] += 1

# print output 
for ID in count_dict:
    count = count_dict[ID]
    print(ID + '\t' + str(count))
```